# Why do all USB-C or USB-A always show 5V on a multimeter?

Tags: usb

I bought a MakerHawk USB 3.0 Tester, USB Power Meter to test my USB charging ports in all my charging blocks.  The Blocks have USB-A, USB-A ports, and USB-C.  The USB-C are fast charging ports with PD(3.0) and PPS that can charge devices quickly 20W to 60W.

The Apple Chargers are 20 Watts.

How come when I attach the tester to a USB-C port using an C to A adapter or even just the USB-A connection all the chargers (c ports, and A ports) always show 5V's

[image].

I would have thought that the C fast chargers would show more voltage?  Everything attached to the MeterHawk always reads 5 v's.  The Charger below is capable of 60W's and charges a Pixel from 0 to 100% in less than an hour.  What am I not understanding.

Answer (score 3):

USB supply must always be 5V unless negotiated to some other value by a device that can operate at higher voltage.

Type-C connectors also must be unpowered until something that can be fed power is plugged in, such as Type-C to Type-A adapter in your picture, so you will get 5V as the adapter can only work with 5V devices. Only exception is when you have a Type-A to Type-C adapter then the 5V can be present on Type-C even if nothing is connected to it.

Comment: In theory USB Power Delivery isn't strictly limited to type C. The PD 2.0 specification allows both CC pin communication, and BFSK over vbus (based on never implemented PD 1.0 spec). I'm not sure if more than a few non-type C chargers or devices have ever been released, but they are theoretically legal. Type C devices that support PD must support negotiating it over CC pin, with FBSK being optional. Non-type-C devices that implement PD must implement FBSK. When using a non-type-C charger, only non-type-C chargees are guaranteed compatible (type C chargees might not implement BFSK protocol).

Comment: Similarly, with a non-type-C PD chargee, only non-type-C PD chargers are guaranteed to work, since others won't implement BFSK. The biggest issue is that non type-C PD need special PD cables, that can handle at least 3A (while some normal cables could safely handle that, the charger can't tell those from cords that can't handle it). All conformant Type-C to Type-C support up to 3A at up to 20V charging. Some special cables support up to 100W (up to 5A at 20V) or 240W (5A EPR cables can support up to 48V). See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/544036/5340

Comment: @KevinCathcart Not correct, USB specs do not allow more than 3A when used without PD so all cables up to 3A are OK. Only with PD more than 3A can be used and you need cables that have e-marker chip to indicate support for more than 3A.

Comment: That is only true for type-c, which I mention in my comment. USB PD Revision 2.0 Version 1.3 Section 3.3.1 limits non-type-C unmarked cables to 5V 1.5A: "Devices Shall only use these non-marked legacy cable assemblies at vSafe5V and up to 1.5A as described by [...]". Unmarked type-C cables on the other hand do allow 20V at 30A.

Answer (score 1):

Voltages other than "Safe +5V" can only be negotiated on Type-C connectors, where the CC1 and CC2 (communication channel) is present. Both link partners must see this channel. Type-A connectors do not have the CC channel, so no PowerDelivery negotiations can possibly occur, and any "C-to-A" adapter will be left with static default advertising (5V@900/1500/3000mA)